# Auto restart crashed heroku app

Tags: heroku, restart

My app sometimes crashes and I would like to know if there is a Add-on or Dyno that I can deploy which will detect when my app is crashed and restart is automatically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no add-on which will auto-deploy your crashed app on heroku, but here's a work around.

- Use a log-management add-on(like [papertrail](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/papertrail))
- Watch out for log messages you get when your heroku app crashes.
- Add custom web-hooks that gets triggered whenever you app gives one of those error-logs that correspond to an app crash.
- Make these web-hooks to call a custom service that redeploys your application. https://help.papertrailapp.com/kb/how-it-works/web-hooks/

When you encounter an "app crash" situation, it usually means only the "web dyno" is crashed. Your service workers might still be running. Though this approach answers your query, I would recommend not to use it in practice because you would want to manually see you logs, find the reason for app-crash and fix it so you don't have to face it in future.

Comment: Is this possible to config Heroku to send a noticed email to owner when app in web dyno crashed ?